# How to start co-op in Halo MCC?

Tags: halo-the-master-chief-collection

I seem to have searched the menus everywhere, but I can't find how to start a co-op mode in Halo Master Chief Collection.

I only know Halo Reach, where it was under multiplayer > matchmaking > coop, or something like that. Here, I can only find versus modes in the multiplayer menu.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is invite the player to your party & game (or just game). and they will be added in your roster.

Alternatively, they could just open up their roster menu, select you, and then select join.

Split screen co-op is simply press A on controllers that are involved(they must be on and connected) once you select the game to play.

Comment: OK but I don't know anyone playing Halo. How can I play with unknown players like I could in Reach ?

Comment: there is no matchmaking for co-op play.

Comment: This is so sad :(

Comment: Try reddit perhaps?